# peer not authenticated - Rally javatoolkit error

Tags: ssl, rally

I have been using the rally javatoolkit for a while to add testcases, test results etc without any error. But all of a sudden it started throwing error as 
" `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`" . I have referred the pages "[rally rest api java toolkit sslpeerunverifiedexception : peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506119/rally-rest-api-java-toolkit-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated)" , [rally rest api java toolkit sslpeerunverifiedexception : peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506119/rally-rest-api-java-toolkit-sslpeerunverifiedexception-peer-not-authenticated/14507182#14507182) but they didn't help me. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong. Also If i need to download a certificate please help me for windows system. Thanks in advance. my code is as below:

```
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;


public class ConnnectionTestWithHTTPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String apiKey = "_abc123";
        String applicationName = "Connnection Test With HTTPClient";
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 
        //restApi.setProxy(new URI("http://myproxy.mycompany.com"), "MyProxyUsername", "MyProxyPassword");  //SET PROXY SETTINS HERE
        HttpClient client = restApi.getClient();
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                    //trust all certs
                    return true;
                }
            }, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, sf));

            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345"; //USE VALID WORKSPACE OID 
            GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(workspaceRef);
            GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
            System.out.println(getResponse.getObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   
    } 
}
```

Also adding to the issue, i found a different error when I changed the port from 443 to 8443. i get "`java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 522 Origin Connection Time-out`" when i use 8443.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I uncomment the line `//restApi.setProxy(new URI("http://myproxy.mycompany.com"), "MyProxyUsername", "MyProxyPassword");` with correct inputs, the error goes off. 
For all those who need the inputs, please put in the following:

```
restApi.setProxy(new URI("http://rally1.rallydev.com"), "xyz@abc.com", "rallypassword");
```

so the working code is as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;

public class ConnnectionTestWithHTTPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String apiKey = "_apikey"; 
        String applicationName = "Connnection Test With HTTPClient";
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 
        restApi.setProxy(new URI("http://rally1.rallydev.com"), "abc@abc.com", "rallypassword");  //YOUR PROXY SETTINGS HERE
        HttpClient client = restApi.getClient();
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                    //trust all certs
                    return true;
                }
            }, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, sf));

            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1234"; 
            GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(workspaceRef);
            GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
            System.out.println(getResponse.getObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   
    } 
}
```