# How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated Exception in Rally Rest api using java?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, rally

This is my code.
I want to fetch data from Rally Api using QueryResponse. But it is showing javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated  exception peer not authenticated. I am trying to use this 
 java toolkit to test Rally's webservice api. We have an internal setup of Rally. My code looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException 
    {
        String projectRef = "/project/123";
        RallyRestApi restpoint = new RallyRestApi(new URI("http://rally1.rallydev.com"), "_api key");   


        // i have added following section because which is given as a solution for above exception. but then also it is giving me javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated exception
        HttpClient client = restpoint.getClient();         
        try 
        {             
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(new TrustStrategy() {                 
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificate, String authType) throws CertificateException 
                {                     //trust all certs                     
                    return true;                 
                    }}, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);             
            client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, sf));  

        }catch (Exception e) 
        {             
            System.out.println(e);        

        }
        try {
            String version = restpoint.getWsapiVersion();
            System.out.println("version : " + version);
            QueryRequest defects = new QueryRequest("hierarchicalrequirement");

            defects.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Owner", "Name", "State", "Iteration", "Project", "Defect", "ScheduleState", "PlanEstimate"));
            defects.setOrder("FormattedID ASC"); 
            defects.setProject(projectRef);
            defects.setQueryFilter(
                    new QueryFilter("Iteration.StartDate", ">=", "2017-10-01"));
            //Return up to 5, 1 per page
            defects.setPageSize(1);
            defects.setLimit(10);

            QueryResponse queryResponse = restpoint.query(defects); //here i am getting above exception

 //following code is printing the JSON data
            if (queryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("\nTotal results: %d", queryResponse.getTotalResultCount()));

                for (JsonElement result : queryResponse.getResults()) {
                    JsonObject defect = result.getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonObject project = defect.getAsJsonObject("Project");
                    JsonObject itr = defect.getAsJsonObject("Iteration");
                    JsonObject def = defect.getAsJsonObject("Defect");
                    //System.out.println(defect.toString());
                    System.out.println(String.format("User Story ID: %-10s \nName Of Story: %-30s: \nOwner: %-10s \nProject: %-15s \nStatus: %s",
                            defect.get("FormattedID").getAsString(),
                            defect.get("Name").getAsString(),
                            defect.get("Owner").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject().get("_refObjectName"),
                            project.get("Name").getAsString(),
                            defect.get("ScheduleState").getAsString()
                            ));
                    System.out.println();System.out.println();



                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("The following errors occurred: ");
                for (String err : queryResponse.getErrors()) {
                    System.err.println("\t" + err);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                restpoint.close();  //closing rally Api
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   




        }
```

Comment: JayeshK, You mention in your question that you, "...have an internal setup of Rally", however you are connecting to the SaaS URL for Agile Central.  What URL do you use to login to Agile Central via a Web Browser?

Comment: I use same URL which mentioned in the program

Comment: Thank you for the clarification JayeshK.  I am thinking it may be a proxy issue now as described in this post, [peer not authenticated - Rally javatoolkit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591692/peer-not-authenticated-rally-javatoolkit-error).  See the part where the poster mentions adding the proxy configuration fixes the issue for them.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you.....it was a proxy issue

Comment: OK, good news!  I should have posted that as the answer instead of a comment.  I will post that now as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this similar post, [peer not authenticated - Rally javatoolkit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591692/peer-not-authenticated-rally-javatoolkit-error)

Specifically the part where the poster mentions that adding the proxy configuration fixes the issue for them.

Hopefully that helps.