# Rally Rest API used in a windows service

Tags: api, rest, windows-services, rally

I'm writing a windows service that uses the Rally Rest API.  The below code works fine when not run as a service.

api = new RallyRestAPI(new URI(url), user, pass);

but when I try to use it:

QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("workspace");
QueryResponse response = api.query(request);

I get
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)

Note, if I pass in bad credentials I get a different error (in both service and non-service invocations ).  I've also tried extending RallyRestAPI using the OnPremRestApi as described in [SSLPeerUnverifiedException with httpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101763/sslpeerunverifiedexception-with-httpclient)

I've tried all of the variations on the windows service Log On tab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't trust our SSL cert. I assume that depends on how you set up your server in the first place but we don't have any windows Admins to ask :(

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem had to:
Go to the Rally Sigon page in my browser and download the cert from the little paddalock icon.
Import the cert into my jre/lib/security/cacerts keystore.
Then all is well